# Calling dplyr::everything() in function causes Travis CI build to fail

Tags: r, dplyr, travis-ci

I'm working on an R package hosted on GitHub.  When I add `dplyr::everything()` to my function, it causes the Travis CI build to fail (though it installs fine locally).  The Travis error blames the `everything()` function in dplyr, and sure enough, when I remove it, the problem is solved.
The function is:

```
get_dupes <- function(dat, ...) {
  dupes <- dat %>%
    dplyr::group_by(...) %>%
    dplyr::filter(n() > 1)  %>%
    dplyr::mutate(dupe_count = n()) %>%
    dplyr::select(..., dupe_count, dplyr::everything()) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>%
    dplyr::arrange(...)

  var_names <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L], deparse)

  if(nrow(dupes) == 0){return(paste0("No duplicate combinations found of: ", paste(var_names, collapse = ", ")))}
  dupes
}
```

Removing that `dplyr::everything()` call resolves the problem - but then the function doesn't do what I want (return all the variables).

The Travis error message includes:

```
>>> Filename: janitor.Rcheck/00install.out <<<
* installing *source* package â€˜janitorâ€™ ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object â€˜everythingâ€™ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package â€˜janitorâ€™
* removing â€˜/home/travis/build/sfirke/janitor/janitor.Rcheck/janitorâ€™
```

Why is `everything()` behaving differently than the other dplyr functions I'm using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `everything` is not a function exported by dplyr.

```
> library(dplyr)
> everything
Error: object 'everything' not found
> dplyr:::everything
function (vars) 
{
    seq_along(vars)
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Use 3 colons `:::` to access unexported functions from a namespace or package. Or in this case, since it's so simple, you could just use `seq_along` directly in your `select` call (since it's bad form to refer to someone else's unexported objects when writing a package).

Edit: actually, you should be able to just do `dplyr::select(*, everything())` without explicitly specifying the namespace for `everything`. This is because when `select` is called, the search path in which it looks for objects will include its own namespace.

Comment: Helpful example - I'm locally using the dev version of dplyr from GitHub, 0.4.3.9001, and now I see that this function was only exported as of [a commit in March](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/2151d8b75e9d9d76ce59d1863acbdf103b4f537a) and is not yet in the CRAN version. Thus my confusion and the Travis failure. Not specifying the namespace for `everything` worked!